# Linq join table and create dynamic column error

Tags: c#, linq, join

I would like to do something create dynamic column in Linq for my joined table.

This is my code after asking around. But it give me another error like this.

Code:

```
var SelectedDT1AndDt2= from dr1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                       join dr2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                       on dr1.Field<Int64>("id1") equals 
                       dr2.Field<Int64>("id2") into joinDt1AndDt2
                       from leftjoin in joinDt1AndDt2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select dtJoinedTable.LoadDataRow(
                       (from dc1 in dt1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() 
                        select dc1.ColumnName.ToString()).ToArray()
                        .Union(from dc2 in dt2.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                        select dc2.ColumnName).ToArray()
                       , false);
SelectedDT1AndDt2.CopyToDataTable();
```

Error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store  in id Column.  Expected type is Int64.

Comment: Can you provide more information (like types and technologies). Your title looks like an error message, yet you provide a different error message in the body of your post. Are they related? Have you tried doing what you are trying to do piecemeal and figuring out in what step the error occurs?

Comment: Sorry, my title error is wrong, I didn't realize it when I post, the error in the post is the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the column import is not type Int'64', I check again and confirm that the original col type is Int'32'.